# How to update product name for main website and all store

Tags: product, database, magento2.3, product-attribute

I am updating the product name and it only affects the En store view I want to update product name for all store views and main website as well. see the sample code below

```
   $sku = 'E20630';
    $product = $this->getProductBySku($sku);
    if ($product) {
        $product->setName('New Name');
        $this->productRepository->save($product);
        $response = ['success' => 'ok', 'message' => 'product updated'];
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($response); exit;
    }
```

For En store product name is changed
[image]

For All Store Views, product name is not changed
[image]

Comment: I hope this link will help you. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/191700/magento-2-saving-update-product-in-all-store-views

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your endpoint only points to the EN scope, your default view.

If you connect to endpoints **/rest/V1/products** the data is stored in the default store view. Write to the globale scope can be done with endpoints like this: **/rest/all/V1/products**. On the other hand you can use the "storeviewcode" to update specific views. For this task you can adapt your path in following way: **/rest/{storeviewcode}/V1/products**.

You will also find your answer in Thread [Scope of Endpoints](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/259002/magento-2-2-6-attributes-issue-with-store-view-and-product-created-by-rest/259163#259163).